# Capybara & Bootstrap dropdown not able to select an option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, capybara

Here's the dropdown menu:

```
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select dropup open">
  <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-default" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="taggings_tag_id" title="Nothing selected" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="filter-option pull-left">Nothing selected</span>&nbsp;<span class="bs-caret"><span class="caret"></span></span>
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu open" style="max-height: 484px; overflow: hidden; min-height: 92px;">
    <ul class="dropdown-menu inner" role="menu" style="max-height: 472px; overflow-y: auto; min-height: 80px;">
      <li data-original-index="0" class="selected">
        <a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null">
          <span class="text"></span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark">
          </span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li data-original-index="1">
        <a tabindex="0" class="" style="" data-tokens="null">
          <span class="text">Create Account</span>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok check-mark"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <select class="selectpicker" id="taggings_tag_id" name="taggings[tag_id]" tabindex="-98">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Create Account</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I'm trying to select that "Create Account" option from the dropdown. I can get capybara to click on the dropdown and expand the list, but I can't get it to select the correct option--resulting in a null value failure when it clicks on Add Tag.

```
it 'adds a tag' do
  page.find(:xpath, "//button[@title='Nothing selected']").click
  option=all("ul.dropdown-menu.inner > li").last
  option.click
  find('input[value="Add Tag"]').trigger("click")
  expect(page).to have_content 'Create Account'
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because no elements is a valid return, `#all` doesn't wait for elements to appear on the page by default.  Since your dropdown probably has an animation when it's opening, `#all` is looking for the element before it's had time to appear on the page.  There are a couple of solutions you could use

1. `option=all("ul.dropdown-menu.inner > li", count: 2).last`

Force it to wait for 2 li elements to be visible on the page - could also use minimum, maximum, between.

2. `option=find("ul.dropdown-menu.inner > li", text: "Create Account")`

Look for the li by its content which will automatically wait for it to appear.

Note:  this will only work if the li accepts the click -- you may need to adjust the selectors to select the  element if that's where the click is listened for.

Comment: Using `option=all("ul.dropdown-menu.inner > li > a > span", text: "Create Account")` results in
`    1) coordinator views chat logs user views a chat log details adds a tag
     Failure/Error: option.click
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method 'click' for #<Capybara::Result:0x007fc4d1a79bd8>
     # ./spec/features/reporting_spec.rb:172:in block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
    Finished in 4.2 seconds
    3 examples, 1 failure`

Comment: @MikeEarley - yes because for that you should be using `#find` as solution 2 does -- not `#all`